# How to escape Android startup restriction

Tags: java, android, startup, restriction, bootcompleted

I am going to create an application running on startup. Is there any tricky way to escape startup restriction? I ask this because I see several application in running app list although they are restricted in startup manager. How to do so?

Edit: Settings->Personal->Startup manager. There you can restrict startup applications. I have simple startup app which does not start for being restricted, but I find restricted apps in running app list(Settings->Manage apps) immediately after boot; so it is possible but how?

Comment: *"escape startup restriction"* can you explain what you are talking about?

Comment: Settings->Personal->Startup manager. There you can restrict startup applications. I have simple startup app which does not start for being restricted, but I find restricted apps in running app list(Settings->Manage apps) immediately after boot; so it is possible but how?

Comment: SO is a place for developer, therefore you should use the development names - in your case I assume you are talking about `BOOT_COMPLETED`.